# Instance of 'MongoEngine' has no 'StringField' member

Tags: mongodb, flask, mongoengine, flask-mongoengine

Trying to create a models for WTForms using Mongo Engine according to the documentation [here](http://docs.mongoengine.org/projects/flask-mongoengine/en/latest/) and getting the error returned Instance of 'MongoEngine' has no 'StringField' member when trying to create a model as such

```
class Example(db.Document):
      Value = db.StringField(max_length=200)
```

Comment: how did you import `db`?

Answer (score 2):

The workaround is to use `mongoengine` package directly, which is installed as a dependency of `flask_mongoengine`.

```py
from mongoengine import StringField

class Example(db.Document):
  value = StringField(max_length=200)
```

The error is provided by `pylint` - a code analysis tool for python, it just fails to validate dynamic members of `db`. Your code is correct it will won't fail at runtime.

Another option is to setup project `.pylintrc` to silence such warnings, or place pylint comments over the line displaying error:

```py
# pylint: disable=no-member
value = db.StringField(max_length=200) # no error
```